# Capybara click_link method patch

Tags: testing, capybara, rspec3

How to tell capybara to send patch method?
default occurs get.

```
     resources :users do
      member do
       patch :toggle_moderator
     end
```

Test

```
  describe 'toggle moderator' do
   it 'remove moderator privilegue', js: true do
     click_on("toogle")
     expect(page).to have_css('.icon-star')
   end
  end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/users/5/toggle_moderator"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in your page. Capybara sends a `GET` request by default, because that's what browsers send, and Capybara is simulating a browser.

To send a `PATCH` request, you'll need to have some JavaScript code attached to the click handler for your link. If you do, there may be a bug in it that is causing this to happen.